# std::vector<std::vector<Vertex>> vertex_matrix; was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, vector, g++, std

In one .cpp file, I declare and implement a class "Vertex". Then I declare and implement second class "ThreeDimensionObject". Inside ThreeDimensionObject
, it has one public member std::vector> vertex_matrix;

I did import . The project runs fine on xCode IDE and g++ prompt me "error: ‘vertex_matrix’ was not declared in this scope".

How can I fix it?

```
#include <vector>
class Vertex : public std::vector<float>
{
   //implementation
};

class ThreeDimensionObject
{
    //the center position
public:  
    //num_stack * num_stack * 4
    std::vector<std::vector<Vertex>> vertex_matrix;
};
```

Comment: As an unrelated side note, a `std::vector` is an incredibly awful way to represent a vertex in 3-space, as it uses a dynamically allocated block of memory for what should just be 3 or 4 floats (and that block takes up about as much additional overhead as those 4 floats themselves, not to forget the `std::vector`'s automatic storage itself, that is also as large as the actual vertex data itself). If you really want a standard library container for vertices, then at least settle for a `std::array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defination of 'vertex_matrix' should be,

```
std::vector<std::vector<Vertex> > vertex_matrix;
```

Your code compiles with c++11 flag but without c++11 flag it needs an extra space.

Comment: Thank you! This works. I am working on school, which does not allow use c++ 11.

Answer (score 2):

The code compiles fine on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/qFOrum) when compiled as [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11). When compiled without the C++.11 flags, the code emits the following error:

```
prog.cpp:12:35: error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list
     std::vector<std::vector<Vertex>> vertex_matrix;
```

This error probably occurred near the top of your list of errors, and you may not have seen it. You can compile the code as C++ 11 (by adding `-std=gnu++11` or `-std=c++11` to the `g++` command line), or you can add the needed space.

```
    std::vector<std::vector<Vertex> > vertex_matrix;
```

Comment: +1 Assuming the OP (or anyone else) uses the canned clang from Apple, to ensure C++11 compliance in Xcode, (1). Select the project in the solution, (2) Select All+Combined in the settings window, (3) Scroll to Build Options and select "Apple LLVM ..." for the compiler, (4) Scroll down to the "Apple LLVM 4.2 compiler - Language" settings and set the C++ Language Dialect setting to be "C++11 (-std=c++11)" That should do it. g++ settings are a little different, but in the same settings location of Xcode.